# Logic error in undo redo

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Hey guys I've been stuck on this problem for 2 days.
I cant seem to make this bit of code work:http://www.taffatech.com/Paint.html
draw 3 dots, click undo 2 times and it does what its supposed to, so I am hopefully it cant be too much to fix.
I had the undo redo tied to 2 buttons 'undo' and 'redo' they are here:

-Update, this might make more sense?
I GOT IT WORKING except it now removes two then after that it does it normally 1 by 1

```
   function clearCanvas()
    {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);

    }
   Stack1 = new Stack();
    ///////////////////

    function Stack() {
    var currentState = 0;
    var maxStates = 10;
     var stateArray = [];

var image = new Image();
image.id = "pic";
image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
stateArray.push(image);


    this.add = function() {
       var image = new Image();
image.id = "pic";
image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
stateArray.push(image);
currentState++;
    }

    this.undo = function () {



stateArray.pop();
currentState--;
clearCanvas();
var image = stateArray[curentState];
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);

    }

    this.redo = function () {
    alert("worry about later");
       // if (stackIndex%stackSize == stackTop) return;
        //clearCanvas();
        //var tmpImg = new Image();
       // tmpImg.src = drawStack[++stackIndex%stackSize];
       // ctx.drawImage(tmpImg, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that you are incrementing your `currentState` right *after* you push a new stack which means it currently pointing to an empty entry.

Then you decrement it in the undo which means it now points to the current one you just saved - which is what you have on your screen in the very moment.

Therefor you won't see any change the first time you hit undo, but only for the next ones.

What you need to do is to only increment `currentState` when you *start* to draw something new (ie. your mouse-down event). That will indicate that the next slot will be filled with current operation.  When you then hit undo, it will work correctly as now it goes back to the previous state.

Process:

```
Init currentState = -1

StartDraw
    currentState++
    clear items in stack from this position to max

EndDraw
    fill array at currentState

Undo
    currentState--
    if < 0 set = -1 and clear canvas
    else update canvas

Redo
    currentState++
    if > array.length -1 exit
    if >= max set = max -1 and rotate array
    update canvas at currentState
```

Comment: this.undo = function () {
    
    
    
    if(currentState > 0)
     {
    currentState--;

      //stateArray.pop();
      clearCanvas();
     var image = stateArray[currentState];
      ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
      }
    

    }

Answer (score 1):

On your site, your stackSize variable is undefined.  The code pasted above is slightly different, in the link provided the stack size is passed to the `function stack(`.  However, you are not passing any size to the constructor and the value is undefined.

Comment: I have updated my post with new code, this might make more sense? Can you help?